# How to get top,left of the element which mouse went over on it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mouseevent, mouseover

I want to get the element's top-left position in the document which the mouse went over on it, but strangely it is telling me all of it's style has not been setted. for example if you try  below code in stackoverflow or in this page, it should give us the position of question-header, but it prints empty.

```
document.getElementById("question-header").addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
console.log(e.target.style.top )
})
```

like below:

[image]

How should i do it properly?

Comment: can you proide your css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with vanilla js you can do something like:

```js
document.getElementById("question-header").addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
  const element = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = element.left;
  const top = element.top;
  const width = element.width;
  const height = element.height;

  console.log(`Left: ${left}, Top: ${top}, Width: ${width}, Height: ${height}`);
})
```

If you need to get all the computed styles, you can do something like:

```js
document.getElementById("question-header").addEventListener("mouseover",(e)=>{
  const elementStyles = getComputedStyle(e.target);
  console.log(elementStyles);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you please tell how should we get the other styles of the target element?(it seems the width and height are changing, why?)

Comment: @SeyyedKhandon I updated the original answer with the snippet to get the styles from a element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById("question-header").addEventListener("mouseover",function(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
 console.log(x,y);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).mouseover(function(){
  var x = $("#question-header").position();
  console.log("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Try this answer in the console of the same page ypu will get the values.